# Expectation of seating arrangements

Tags: probability, permutations

Question: $5$ men and $5$ women are seated randomly in a single row of chairs. The expected number of women sitting next to at least $1$ man equals ?

The answer is $35/9$. Could somebody please show the workings to this question because I'm getting stuck in the very first step of gauging the probability of the random variable $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a particular woman W. What's the probability she's sitting next to at least one man? Well this depends on whether she's sitting at the end of the row or not, so it's easier to split into two cases.

If W is sitting on the end (probability $1/5$), there is one person next to her, and $5$ men out of the $9$ other people, so the probability it's a man is $5/9$.

If W is not sitting on the end, (probability $4/5$), there are two people next to her. The number of possible pairs of people to sit next to her is $\binom 92=36$, and all of these are equally likely. The number of pairs of other women is $\binom 42=6$, so the probability she is sitting next to at least one man is $5/6$.

So the probability W is sitting next to at least one man is $\frac 15\times\frac59+\frac45\times\frac56=\frac79$. Now the expected number of women is just this probability times the total number of women.

Comment: Thanks a lot Especially Lime!

Comment: One doubt though, what are the values of the random variable W here ?.

Comment: W isn't a random variable, it's a particular woman you choose at the start (before you put anyone in any seats). Then W has probability $7/9$ of being put next to at least one man, and because you could have picked any woman to be W, they all have the same probability.

Comment: okay, so I guess there isnt a need to define a random variable so as to calculate expectation over here.

Comment: Well, what's really going on is we're calculating the expectation of the variable which is $1$ if W is next to a man, and $0$ if she isn't. Then we do that for each other woman, and add them up. But the expectation of that variable is just the probability of W being next to a man.