# Expectation of seating arrangements? Why is this approach wrong?

Tags: probability

Consider [this question on arrangements of seats.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337993/expectation-of-seating-arrangements) Why does this approach fail?

> Question: 5 men and 5 women are seated randomly in a single row of chairs. The expected number of women sitting next to at least 1 man equals ?

> The answer is 35/9. Could somebody please show the workings to this question because I'm getting stuck in the very first step of gauging the probability of the random variable X.

$K_i = \begin{Bmatrix} 1& Woman \; sits \; next \; to \; at \; least \;one \; man\; at \; position\; i   \\ 0& Otherwise \end{Bmatrix} $

$E  [K_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{10} P(K_i) $

For positions 2-9, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that the seat is occupied by a woman and $ 1- (\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2})$ chance that some man is sitting next to it. So expected number of women sitting next to at least one man from positions 2-9 will be $8 \times \frac{1}{2} \times\frac{3}{4}= 3$. For the two corner cases, it would be $2\times \frac{1}{2} \times\frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{2}$ . Adding the two we get $ 3+ \frac{1}{2} = \frac{7}{2}$. The given answer is $\frac{35}{9}$. Why is this approach wrong?

Comment: If a seat is occupied by a woman the chance that a neighboring one is occupied by a man is $\frac 59$.  The chance that at least one neighboring seat is occupied by a man is then ?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is fine, however you are making errors based on the fact that these seats are filled *without replacement* from the available people.

"*For positions 2-9, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that the seat is occupied by a woman and $1-(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2})$ chance that some man is sitting next to it*"

This is where your error is.  Calling it a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of being occupied by a woman in that seat is fine.  As we continue on, however, everything later will be *conditioned* on this fact.  We can do as you started, looking at the complementary event... so $1$ minus the probability of both of these neighboring seats being women.  The seat to the left would also be a woman *given that the first seat had a woman* would be $\frac{4}{9}$.  The seat to the right would also be a woman *given that both the seat to the left and the original seat both had women* would be $\frac{3}{8}$.

The corrected statement here would have been "*For positions 2-9, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that the seat is occupied by a woman and $1-(\frac{4}{9}\times\frac{3}{8})$ chance that given it was occupied by a woman that at least one man is sitting next to it*"

Similarly, your corner cases need fixing.

The final calculation should have been, following your setup:

$$8\times \frac{1}{2}\times (1-\frac{4}{9}\times\frac{3}{8}) + 2\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{5}{9}=\frac{35}{9}$$